# Boolean method can not return anything

Tags: java, android, multithreading, return, boolean

I am working on an Android app, and now I am writing some methods for the login system. I am trying to create a `boolean` method that returns true or false according to the response of the server. This is my code:

```
public static boolean login(final String name, final String password) {

    final boolean result;
    Thread nt = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {


            URL url;
            HashMap<String, String> postDataParams = new HashMap<String, String>();

            postDataParams.put("name", name);
            postDataParams.put("password", password);

            try {

                url = new URL("");

                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setReadTimeout(15000);
                conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                conn.setDoInput(true);
                conn.setDoOutput(true);


                OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                        new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));

                writer.flush();
                writer.close();
                os.close();
                int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();

                if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                return false;
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    };
    nt.start();
}
```

The problem is that every return statement gets highlighted because `cannot return a value from a method with void result type`, something I can not understand, because it is clearly defined as a `boolean` method. I suppose, it has something to do with the new thread I created, but since this app will be running on an Android device, I haveve to run my query in a separate thread.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: may be you can try to wait for the thread to finish, and from the thread change a local variable to the function `boolean login` and make a return after the function pass the wait statement

Answer (score 3):

All of your code is within the `public void run()` method, which returns `void`.
Therefore returning `boolean` is not allowed.

Comment: Wow, I didn't consider that detail. Such a mistake. How could I fix it?

Comment: You make a boolean result variable outside run (still inside login) and then instead of calling "return true/false" inside run, you call result = true/false and then do a void return afterwards. After the run is over you return the result variable as the return value for login... I'll make an answer with this info just in case.

Comment: @pitazzo I've addressed the latest issue you mentioned in a separate answer

Answer (score 0):

It is all about scope. You can't start a new thread and then return the value from inside the thread scope. The `run()` method inside the Thread class has a void return type.

You would have to remove the thread and then put the code directly in the method. But because it's android, it won't allow connections on main thread, so you have to create a callback interface and once the site is loaded inside the thread, you call a method inside the interface with the result: true or false.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, the cause of the compilation errors is that you are trying to return a value in the `run()` method of an anonymous `Runnable` instance.  The `run()` method is a void method.

In a comment, you asked how you could "fix it" so that your `login` method can return the result.

The simple answer is to get rid of the thread and `run()` method and do the work directly in the `login` method; e.g.

```
public static boolean login(final String name, final String password) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL("some url");

        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setReadTimeout(15000);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);

        OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
        // write the post data ...
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
        os.close();
        int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
        return (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
```

If `login` has to return a value, then that value needs to be available when the method returns.  It is synchronous.  If you do the work in a (another) thread, then the current thread has to 1) wait for that other thread to finish, and 2) get the result from that thread.  You can do it, but it is pointless.

If your goal is to avoid blocking the current thread when `login` is called, then the `login` method needs to return a `Future` or something like that.  But ultimately, the code that uses the success / failure status for the login will need to call `Future.get`.  That may need to wait for the result, and therefore block the thread.

The best answer may be to redesign your UI's state machine.